# Apache hangs frequently, needs restart to work again

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, apache2.4

i am having issues tuning apache.
My current mpm event configs are

```
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
  ServerLimit               24
  StartServers               8
  MinSpareThreads          512
  MaxSpareThreads          768
  ThreadsPerChild           64
  MaxRequestWorkers       1536
  MaxConnectionsPerChild  5000
</IfModule>
```

if i continuously press ctrl+r on my site for like 20 sec apache hangs, and i need to restart the server
On heavy traffic hours also it happens, usually in a day more than 5 times  i am facing a downtime.
I am reading forums for tuning apache mpm event but not able to figure out.Can anyone please help on this issue or suggest a change or so in my current setup to achieve max performance without hanging apache.
I am using an Amazon m3 large instance with ubuntu

Comment: Hi, have you noticed some indications in error.log? Or any other hint in access.log setting a higher debug level?

Comment: Looks more like a question for [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) to me.

Comment: nope no errors in logs. access logs also seems good @FrancescoGualazzi

Answer (score 0):

There's a reason why it's called event. It just waits for that event you're not looking. Mine did the same so I switched back to prefork. Worker is even better

Comment: need more information about the context of the question, as well as configuration parameters and logs